# Trying to pass data between activities

Tags: android

Im trying to pass data between two activities using this subject:

[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

### with this answer:

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);

 i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");

 startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  
 if (extras != null) {
     
 String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
   
}
```

My problem is , I'm not success.. I have a game contains a value called coins but it is as a sharedperferences ,
here is the code of the sharedpreferences: (oncreate)

```
prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    coins = prefs.getInt("key2", 0);
```

Now how do I get the amount of coins I got on the Shop(Shop.java) to buy things with them?

Comment: Are you saving the coins value correctly, so you can read it correctly too?

Comment: @joao2fast4u Currently, the coins value is working fine, at my app, every click gains you one more coin, and there is a text that shows the coins you have, it's working fine. but not over an other activity.

Comment: See my edited answer. If it helped you, please accept it/up-vote it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: @KingOmar Dude, I added this link at my own question because I haven't successfully solved it with your link. p.s sry bout my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass your coins value, in your sending `Activity`,  using:

```
i.putExtra("new_variable_name",coins);
```

Note that the second parameter is your int coins value from `SharedPreferences`.

To read your coins value (int value) on the receiving `Activity` you have to read it as an `Integer`, not as a `String`.

So, use:

```
private int coinsValue = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

 if (extras != null) {

     coinsValue = getIntent().getIntExtra("new_variable_name", 0);

}
```

}

And there you go, `coinsValue` variable has your value.

Edit: To use coinsValue anywhere in your receiving class, declare it as a field, at the beginning.

Comment: But then when im trying to buy something on the shop (       coinsValue=coinsValue-500;      ) it says: 

 coinsValue cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: TY! It's working :) now I need to save it again as coins when I'm doing intent to the main page(first) :) ty!

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you get number of coins in SharedPreferences. If you do so, you need to save it to in your Activity -

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
prefs.putInt("key2", coins);
prefs.commit();
```